# I have a task to find bugs in this code and I just can't find any

Tags: c

I study in school c programming and I have this assignment to find 3 bugs in this code. I just can't find any! It all seems to work just fine...
maybe I should also mention that I have been studying for about only 2 months.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LOWER 0
#define UPPER 172486
/*
Bug Report: 
1. 
2.
3.
*/
void welcome(void);
void useage(void);
void getNumber(void);
void printTwice(int number);

int main(void)
{
    welcome();
    return 0;
}

/*
This function prints "welcome".
input: none
output: none
*/
void welcome(void)
{
    printf("Welcome to my cool program!\n");
    useage();
}

/*
This function prints what the program is for.
input: none
output: none
*/
void useage(void)
{
    printf("My program gets a number from you - and prints it twice in a row!\n");
    getNumber();
}

/*
The function gets a number.
input: none
output: none
*/
void getNumber(void)
{
    printf("Please enter a number between 0 - 172,486: \n");
    int number = 0;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    while(number < LOWER || number > UPPER)
    {
        printf("Invalid choice!\n");
        scanf("%d", &number);
    }
    printTwice(number);
}


/*
Prints the number twice. 
input: the number we got from the user.
output: none
*/
void printTwice(int number)
{
    printf("The number twice in a row: %d%d", number, number);
}
```

Comment: 1) check the return value of printf to see if it printed everything... 2) is `int` on your machine able to ingest 172,486 and 3) check the return value of scanf (thanks David ;-)

Comment: I don't know if I should say that it contains any clear bugs. It's just poorly written. :)

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

1.

No warning for entering strings instead of numbers. 00 will be printed.

2.

```
   printf("The number twice in a row: %d%d", number, number);
```

No space between numbers, no line termination
Proposed change:

```
   printf("The number twice in a row: %d %d\n", number, number);
```

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks! Corrected!